# reverse Lightbox effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am looking for a jquery script that does this effect: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3Lightbox/

This one only uses CSS3, but I am looking for jQuery to act as a fallback for older browser support.

Does anyone know how this might be done?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use fadein/out with two images or divs with different classes. But I suggest using only jQuery for all browsers rather than css3 + jQuery. Or css3 and a simple hover effect for those with old IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this script to have slightly different opacity values and it should work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/gYyBL/

HTML:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/vdDQgb.jpg" hoverImg="http://i.imgur.com/Epl4db.jpg">
```

JS:

```
$('body').find('*[hoverImg]').each(function(index){
    $this = $(this)
    $this.wrap('<div>')     
    $this.parent().css('width',$this.width())  
    $this.parent().css('height',$this.width())
    $this.parent().css('background-image',"url(" + $this.attr('hoverImg')+")")
        $this.hover(function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',.01)    
        },function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',1)             
        })                    
});
```